# Two or more sources in autocomplete jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

Is it possible to have two or more sources in a autcomplete?
my two arrays:

```
        var availableTags = [];
    $("#toggles h3").each(function() {
           availableTags.push( $(this).text()); 
        });
    var availableAns = [];
    $(".answer").each(function() {
        availableAns.push( $(this).text());
      console.log(availableAns);
        });
```

Here is the jquery that gets the source for the autocomplete, it only gets one source now "avaiblableTags" but i want it to get "avaiblableAns" aswell.

```
$( ".autocomplete #input_1_1" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        open: function(event,ui){
    $("#field_1_1 .gfield_label").text($('.ui-autocomplete > li').length +" RESULTATEN");
    }});
```

and doing it like this doesn't work:

```
    $( ".autocomplete #input_1_1" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        source: availableAns,
        open: function(event,ui){
    $("#field_1_1 .gfield_label").text($('.ui-autocomplete > li').length +" RESULTATEN");
    }});
```

now it only gets availableAns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you should use only a single array that combines the values of both `availableTags` and `availableAns`. Why using two different arrays ?
then your new code should be

```
    var availableTags = [];
        $("#toggles h3").each(function() {
               availableTags.push( $(this).text()); 
            });

        $(".answer").each(function() {

            availableTags.push( $(this).text());//here push the values into the same array as used above
          console.log(availableTags);
            });

    $( ".autocomplete #input_1_1" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        open: function(event,ui){
        $("#field_1_1 .gfield_label").text($('.ui-autocomplete > li').length +" RESULTATEN");
    }});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could merge two arrays into one.

```
var all = availableTags.concat(availableAns);

$( ".autocomplete #input_1_1" ).autocomplete({
        source: all,
        open: function(event,ui){
    $("#field_1_1 .gfield_label").text($('.ui-autocomplete > li').length +" RESULTATEN");
}});
```

Comment: where do i place it? and do i cange source: availableTags, to source: all,?